# Calculating weighted mean for values in an array

Tags: php, math

I have an array that contains half-hourly time periods; this array is then sub-divided into dates going back 6 weeks of 'today', each date having the amount of transactions completed on that date, in that half hour period. e.g.

```
 [07:30:00] => Array
        (
            [2015-05-18] => 10
            [2015-05-25] => 17
            [2015-06-01] => 11
            [2015-06-08] => 20
            [2015-06-15] => 16
            [average] => 15
        )

    [08:00:00] => Array
        (
            [2015-05-18] => 12
            [2015-05-25] => 10
            [2015-06-01] => 14
            [2015-06-08] => 19
            [2015-06-15] => 18
            [average] => 15
        )
```

This goes on for the entire business day.

The average I'm currently calculating above is a simple mean of all those values, calculated thus:

```
foreach($average as $half_hour => $data) {
    $average[$half_hour]['average'] = round(array_sum($data)/count($data), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is applying more weight to the more recent dates, and lesser weight to the older values. I started off defining an array of dates I'd encounter, and setting a weight for that particular date:

```
$date_weights = array(
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("6 weeks ago $day")) => 0.05,
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("5 weeks ago $day")) => 0.05,
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("4 weeks ago $day")) => 0.15,
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("3 weeks ago $day")) => 0.20,
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2 weeks ago $day")) => 0.25,
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("1 weeks ago $day")) => 0.30
);
```

The weights all add up to 1, which from what I understand of weighted mean calculations, keeps things simple(r). Except, this is where my poor-math brain threw an exception and refused to play any more.

I tried the following code, but that appears not to do what I'm looking for:

```
foreach($average as $half_hour => $data) {
    // apply the desired weighting to the values
    foreach($data as $date => $transactions) {
        $average[$half_hour][$date] = ($date_weights[$date]*$transactions);
    }
} 

foreach($average as $half_hour => $data) {
    $average[$half_hour]['average'] = round(array_sum($data)/count($data), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

I *think* I'm on the right track here ? But I'm obviously missing a step. Can any kind slightly more math-savvy person point out where I'm going wrong and how best to achieve where I'm trying to get with this? Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the division by `count($data)` so that you get

```
$average[$half_hour]['average'] = round(array_sum($data), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Or pick weights that have an average of (instead of a sum) of one, and keep the division.

Also, if you have 6 weight you need to have 6 values - otherwise the weights don't add up to one. Now you seem to have 6 weights (in `$date_weights` but only 5 values (in `$average[$half_hour]`, not counting `average`).

**EDIT:** If you don't want to worry about the weights adding up to one, you can use this:

```
$average[$half_hour]['average'] = round(array_sum($data)/array_sum($date_weights), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

You still have to make sure all of the weights are used, though.

Comment: Ah ha... thank you for the first part. That solves a headache.  

The second part is also interesting... hmmm... need to have a think about that one because there won't *always* be 6 weeks of data. :-\

** EDIT ** Your edit solves that as well! THANK YOU :D

Comment: Glad it helped! Just remember that even with my second option, you must make sure to use all of the weights. Otherwise it will be as if the value for the last date was zero.

Comment: Need to have a play with this, but you've solved the bulk of the problem :) Thank you